# Is it possible to generate proto datastore classes as Kotlin instead of Java

Tags: android, proto3, android-jetpack-datastore

Currently my proto datastore setup is generating Java classes.  Is it possible to generate Kotlin classes instead?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your `.proto` example command

the kotlin code is produced on top of java code hence it required two flags one for generating java code and another for kotlin code.

```
protoc --proto_path=src --java_out=build/gen/java --kotlin_out=build/gen/kotlin src/foo.proto
```

Source : [More info](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/kotlin-generated#invocation) also check [Kotlin tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/kotlintutorial)

Comment: Do you know if this is built into the gradle plugin? https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#default-outputs

Comment: I don't know, but with some searching I found that this plugin supports for kotlin,
Check sample code 
https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/536

which requires the additional kotlin dependency 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-kotlin